# How to find schematics of a PCB?

Tags: electronic-control-module

I have the following ECU Accent 2012 1.4L, 4-Cyl, 4-speed transmission board in the picture, I have searched for the information written on this product but couldn't find any schematics. Is there a way to extract the schematics of a board or a wiring diagram? I need the voltage values that each component receive, and there are no voltage values written on the board.

[image]

Comment: What board? That looks like the case which is also the heatsink.

Comment: @SolarMike thats an ECU board

Comment: The board is inside...

Comment: I would start at the other end: what sensors connect to this ecu and how do they work - resistance change, open close contacts etc

Comment: Generally auto manufacturers do not publish schematics of these sorts of devices as they consider them to be an FRU (field replaceable unit) vs. something that can be repaired in the field.  While they may have a repair depot that receives these back from dealers and which may salvage or repair them, that is all handled internally.  If you need a schematic you will likely have to create it yourself by tracing out the connections on the board.  This, however, is probably a lot less useful that it might sound as these are usually packed with proprietary parts for which you will not find a source

Comment: @jwh20 you mean like reverse engineering it? Also there are over 100 pins inside that black plastic cover and I don't even know where the power pin is

Comment: Yes, I mean like reverse engineering.  I didn't say it was easy, in fact it can be quite difficult but often it's your only option.

Comment: @jwh20 how is that going to tell which capacitor get what voltage value though? I might be able to figure out what pin goes to what component of my car, but there are 100s of capacitors in the board

Comment: Break out your voltmeter and start probing.  If you get the service manual for your vehicle both the input/output signal lines and the power connections (likely all either +12V or GND) will be shown there.  That's where I would start.  It may be simpler and cheaper in the long run to just get a replacement unit for your car.

Comment: Good luck opening that thing.   They're generally totally 'potted' (i.e. completely embedded in a solid chunk of "stuff".  You're not gonna just open the case and have access to the PCB.  First you gotta melt that potting off.   Re: schematic - Also "good luck".   The OEM has no reason to, and many reasons not to, and thus will not provide you with one.   Take some advice from a complete stranger (who happens to fix alot of cars and is an electrical engineer)  -- Forget this project, suck it up and buy a new computer.   You are not going to be able to service this.

Comment: Re; a WIRING DIAGRAM...  i.e. what the pins mean -- that SHOULD be available as it's critical information for field troubleshooting.  For more popular car makes (i.e. Ford etc) there are commercially available manuals with this information (i.e. "shop manual").    You didn't say what this comes out of, and I've never heard of "Keifco" but I note this is Korean sourced.  Is it a Hyundai???   If a commercial manual is not available, the information will be in the dealers service center's shop manuals.  Whether or not you can get a copy depends on how well you can smooth talk the shop supervisor

Comment: @KyleB that emblem bottom left on the label looks like hyundai and Accent is one of their models.

Comment: @KyleB If you want to track down the detailed schematics, the line that says "Licence Bosch" could be a better starting point than whatever Korean electronics company actually manufactured it.

Comment: @alephzero   I don't.  You're confusing me with the OP   ;)